# Mongo LookUp query With multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, lookup-tables, nosql-aggregation

I have two collection records Like this

```
// collection_1
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64100b43317d38bfe6238deb"),
    "email" : "email@google.com",
    "is_active" : true,
    "stage_id" : 2
}
```

and another Collection Record Is like this

```
// collection_2
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("24003f7f345c72739747b6f9"),
    "collection_1_id":ObjectId("64100b43317d38bfe6238deb"),
    "stage_id" : 2,
    "link":"www.google.com"
}
```

So i wanna do look up query from collection_1 like this

```
select * from collection_1 
join collection_2 
where collection_1._id=collection_2.collection_1_id
and 
collection_1.stage_id=collection_2.stage_id
```

i've searched but i am not able to find way to match multiple fields

Answer (score 1):

You should pipeline in `$lookup`, like this:

```
db.c1.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "c2",
      "let": {
        id: "$_id",
        stageId: "$stage_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              "$and": [
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$$id",
                    "$collection_1_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$$stageId",
                    "$stage_id"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "docs"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qG5b5XzDzM2)